# Is there a "default" file name that can be used for importing modules?

Tags: nim-lang

What I mean is if there's some standard name that can be used for the primary file in a *local* Nim module so that when importing by path, we can simply reference the directory?

For example, it seems right now I need to specify both the directory and file name of the local module like this:

```
import my_module.main
```

Whereas I was hoping to simply be able to reference the directory if the expected file name was found:

```
import my_module
```

Aside from using Nimble or creating a separate `--path` flag for every module in a `nim.cfg` file, is there anything that will allow this?

Also, in general, is there a conventional name to use for the main file of a module?

---

If I have a simple app like this:

```
myapp--+
       |
       +--myapp.nim
       |
       +--sub--+
               |
               +--sub.nim
```

In `myapp.nim` I have to use `import sub.sub` to load the sub-module. With `import sub`, I get `Error: cannot open sub`.

Likewise if I have modules outside the app and set the `--path` to the parent of those modules, I have to use `import my_module.my_module`.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to have a `my_module.nim` and sub-modules in a `my_module` directory. Then you can just `import my_module`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. If I have a sub-module named `sub`, I have to do `import sub.sub` to get it. Likewise if I have modules outside the project and set the `--path` to the parent directory of those modules, I still need to name both the module directory and file in the import. I must be missing something. I'm on the current `devel` branch.

Comment: @LyeFish: `import` works on files, not on directories. The common approach in your case would be to add the subdirectory `sub` to the build path. Not the parent path. Then `import sub` will see the `sub.nim`.

Comment: @bluenote10: I'm a little confused. def- seems to be saying that if you name the `.nim` file the same as its containing directory then you can just name the directory. Am I misunderstanding his answer? This would seem like a useful convention.